# stuck in infinite loop in knight tour backtracking

Tags: c, backtracking, knights-tour

This code is stuck in an infinite loop in the knight tour problem which i am solving using backtracking. I have used `x[8] and y[8]` array to access possible moves in `8` directions. Also I have formed these `x` and `y` arrays same as an already solved answer. But still there is something I am missing and I cant understand what is going wrong.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int x[8] = {  2, 1, -1, -2, -2, -1,  1,  2 };
int y[8] = {  1, 2,  2,  1, -1, -2, -2, -1 };
int sol[100][100]={0};
int isvalid(int i,int j,int n)
{
    if(i>=0&&j>=0&&i<n&&j<n)
    {
        if(sol[i][j]==0)
        return 1;
        else
        return 0;
    }
    return 0;
}
int solvekt(int i,int j,int k,int n)
{
    printf("i=%d j=%d k=%d\n",i,j,k);
    if(k==n*n+1)
    return 1;
    int m,i1,j1,ans=0;
    for(m=0;m<8;m++)
    {
        i1=i+x[m];
        j1=j+y[m];
        if(isvalid(i1,j1,n))
        {
            printf("i=%d j=%d i1=%d j1=%d k=%d\n",i,j,i1,j1,k);
            sol[i1][j1]=k;
            ans=solvekt(i1,j1,k+1,n);
            if(ans)return 1;
            else
            sol[i1][j1]=0;
         }
    }
    return 0;   
 }
int main()
{
    int n=6,i,j;
    sol[0][0]=1;
    if(!solvekt(0,0,2,n))printf("not possible\n");
    else
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<n;j++)
        printf("%d ",sol[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have some prints, so what do you see?

Comment: Meaningful variable and parameter names would go a long way toward making your code easy to understand.

Comment: Are you certain you are in an *infinite* loop, as opposed to simply a *long-running* loop?

Comment: The program prints a large amount of numbers which I did not wait to end. Are any solutions repeated? How many different paths are there in the exhaustive solution? [See this](http://www.borderschess.org/KTsimple.htm)

Comment: I tried to trace the output , but its just going infinite and hard to trace. And I  will improve naming habit . Thanks for suggestion

Comment: Yes I am sure I am in an infinite loop because i have used the x[] and y[] array same as some accepted answer .

Comment: The code doesn't look like having any infinite loop (at least not obvious), so I would bet on a *very long* loop.

Comment: Ran for me and result is `1 16 7 26 11 14  : 
34 25 12 15 6 27  : 
17 2 33 8 13 10  : 
32 35 24 21 28 5  : 
23 18 3 30 9 20  : 
36 31 22 19 4 29  : `  Try `n==5` `1 6 15 10 21  : 
14 9 20 5 16  : 
19 2 7 22 11  : 
8 13 24 17 4  : 
25 18 3 12 23  : `

Comment: I am in no way seeing how the use of the `x` and `y` arrays bears on whether the program loops infinitely.

Comment: It ran for me, too.

Comment: As @chux: remove the two `printf` statements in `solvekt` and it solves almost immediately.

Comment: Got it now. Thanks n sorry for wasting everyone's time

Comment: Iteration count = 248,169 for n=6. Iteration count = 8,250,733 for n=8.  Do not expect recursion depth to exceed `n*n`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OP was impatient. Code is fine, just took a while.

"Are you certain you are in an infinite loop, as opposed to simply a long-running loop? " [@John Bollinger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37977735/stuck-in-infinite-loop-in-knight-tour-backtracking#comment63402020_37977735)

To run *faster*, omit debug prints  [@Weather Vane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37977735/stuck-in-infinite-loop-in-knight-tour-backtracking#comment63402437_37977735)

Comment: With `n==5`, about 50x faster.  Start small and then walk up.